# what is the use of Hibernate Interceptor and proxyTargetClass

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am a newbie to hibernate and spring and trying to learn the use of hibernate Interceptor .
I went through community documentation which says that....

> This interceptor binds a new Hibernate Session to the thread before a
>   method call, closing and removing it afterwards in case of any method
>   outcome. If there already is a pre-bound Session (e.g. from
>   HibernateTransactionManager, or from a surrounding
>   Hibernate-intercepted method), the interceptor simply participates in
>   it.

But I am not able to understand when we use this and why we use this?

when to create taskDao like this ?

```
<bean name="abstractDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="taskHibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="taskHibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="taskSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="taskDaoTarget" class="com.xyz.abc.backgroundtask.impl.TaskDao" parent="abstractDao"/>

<bean id="taskDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>taskHibernateInterceptor</value>
            <value>taskDaoTarget</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and when to create taskDao like this ?

```
<bean name="abstractDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="taskHibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="taskDao" class="com.xyz.zbc.backgroundtask.impl.TaskDao" parent="abstractDao"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use Hibernate Interceptor? Because I'd suggest you use Spring's (annotation based) [Declarative Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) instead. It's a common abstraction for many supported underlying technologies.

Basically, what you do is define a TransactionManager Bean, in the case of Hibernate with JPA:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf"/>
</bean>
```

without JPA:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

In both cases, activate annotation-based transactions:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Or, if you don't use interfaces:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Now annotate your service layer methods or classes with `@Transactional` and you will automatically get sessions created in the scope of your service methods.

I would advise you not to use HibernateInterceptor and HibernateTemplate, they are both just not the modern way to do things anymore.

**Read:**

- [Declarative Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)
- [Using @Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)
- [Implementing DAOs based on plain Hibernate 3 API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight)
- or if you use JPA: [Implementing DAOs based on plain JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight)

And to see how things used to be done in Spring:

- [Classic ORM Usage: The HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html#orm-hibernate-template)